# Laravel RESTFul API Mapping Fields to Model

Tags: php, laravel

We are building a RESTful API with Laravel 4. After doing some initial training with the excellent Laracasts series, one of the tips we were given was to use object transformers to transform our db structure to more readable response fields.. so for example 'user_qual' might become 'user_qualification' and so on. This means changes to the underlying structure don't affect the API definition.

However, we now find that the users will expect to send POST requests in using the same naming convention, so they send in a field called 'user_qualification' which we now need to map to the underlying database table, but this step doesn't seem to be covered in laracasts. What we are doing right now is shown below (for a PUT) and it works, but is there a better way to do this? Before we used the transformers it was easy to just map the input::all() to the model object and update, so I think there must be an easier way! Appreciate any tips!

```
$this->staff = Staff::find($id);
    if (!$this->staff) return $this->respondNotFound('Staff not found', 100);

//map inbound to model
    $newStaffData = array();
    if (Input::has('name')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'name', Input::get('name'));
    if (Input::has('mobile')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'mobile_num', Input::get('mobile'));
    if (Input::has('email')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'email_address', Input::get('email'));
    if (Input::has('employee_id')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'employee_num', Input::get('employee_id'));
    if (Input::has('staff_id')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'unique_id', Input::get('staff_id'));
    if (Input::has('home_number')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'alternate_contact_num', Input::get('home_number'));
    if (Input::has('address_line_1')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'address_line_1', Input::get('address_line_1'));
    if (Input::has('address_line_2')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'address_line_2', Input::get('address_line_2'));
    if (Input::has('address_line_3')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'address_line_3', Input::get('address_line_3'));
    if (Input::has('address_line_4')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'address_line_4', Input::get('address_line_4'));
    if (Input::has('post_code')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'postcode', Input::get('post_code'));
    if (Input::has('country')) $newStaffData = array_add($newStaffData, 'country_id', Input::get('country'));

    $this->staff->fill($newStaffData);

    if (!$this->staff->isValid('update')) {
        return $this->respondCantProcess('Validation Failed - ' . $this->staff->errors, 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) might be of use to you.

There is an easier way, but it's nothing Laravel provides. Just writing better PHP will greatly reduce how much you would need to write. For example:

```
$newStaffData = array(
    'name' => Input::get('name', $this->staff->name),
    'mobile_num' => Input::get('mobile', $this->staff->mobile_num),
    'email_address' => Input::get('email', $this->staff->email_address),
    // ... and so on
);

$this->staff->fill($newStaffData);

if (!$this->staff->isValid('update')) {
    return $this->respondCantProcess('Validation Failed - ' . $this->staff->errors, 100);
}
```

If you're doing this type of coding a lot, I would create a function to simplify the process. For example, you could do something like:

```
function array_trans(array $lookup, $data)
{
    $translated = array();

    foreach($lookup as $from => $to)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($from, $data))
        {
            $translated[$to] = $data[$from];
        }
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Example usage:

```
$lookup = array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'mobile' => 'mobile_num',
    'email' => 'email_address',
);

$newStaffData = array_trans($lookup, Input::get());
```

Comment: Heh thanks so much, that looks good and I will try that later tonight, but I have one question, I am using the same sort of construct for editing a record, and lets say there are 5 fields in that record and the API user only sends three fields to be updated and omits say 'mobile', won't doing something like 'mobile_num' => Input::get('mobile') end up setting 'mobile_num' to '', especially if it already has a value? (this was why I was doing the ' if (input::has()) call... thanks again for your help

Comment: Hi, so I tried this and it works perfectly for a new record via POST but when I try to do a PUT with just one field e.g. 'mobile_num', everything else gets set to blank!

Comment: Actually my bad.. when i used the array_trans function you suggested it worked perfectly! thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry. The first method I should would overwrite existing data with blank data. You could alter example slightly to work around it:

    $newStaffData = array(
        'name' => Input::get('name', $this->staff->name),
        'mobile_num' => Input::get('mobile', $this->staff->mobile_num),
        'email_address' => Input::get('email', $this->staff->email_address),
        // ... and so on
    ); -- updated the answer with the better example.

Comment: thanks! One other small question which is storta related to this. So i do my validation on the mapped object via Validator which perhaps will return an error 'The email field is required', but the user of the API is sending up the field 'email_address', do you know anyway I can change the error messaging to use the field names of the API spec rather than the Model object! I cannot find this anywhere.. thanks

Comment: Customer error messages might be able to do what you're looking for (http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages). You could also collect the error messages, and do something like `array_trans(array_flip($lookup), $errorMessages))`. `array_flip()` will flipflop the keys and values in an array, so it would translate the names in the opposite direction for you.